# What is the difference between principal component analysis (PCA) and principal component regression (PCR)?

Tags: regression, pca

What is the exact difference between principal component analysis (PCA)and principal component regression (PCR)? With what kind of data sets can one  use these methods?

Comment: See [Is principal component regression (PCR) using principal component scores for regression?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/36206/17230) & [How to use principal components as predictors in GLM?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/22665/17230).  [Examples of PCA where PCs with low variance are “useful”](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/101485/17230) is also interesting.

Comment: The question does not show much research effort, but it is formulated such that it can be quite useful for google searches in the future. I don't agree with the downvote. +1.

Comment: @Fati, if you think that Peter answered your question, please "accept" his answer by pressing on a green tick to the left of it.

Answer (score 5):

Principal component analysis is a method of data reduction - representing a large number of variable by a (much) smaller number, each of which is a linear combination of the original variables.

One output of PCA is principal component scores.  Principal component regression uses those scores as independent variables in a regression.

Comment: is it possible explain me with matlab code   or with example   for example if i give one data set with these method what is different in out put of these methods ?

Comment: @fati See references in comment from Scortchi above. These methods are well documented here and elsewhere. Please focus on asking questions that are new here; otherwise the forum is a resource for your study.

Comment: @Nick cox  : i saw but i am not get well my answer .

Comment: I don't know Matlab but the output is completely different.  PCA is a necessary step towards PC regression.  But you can certainly do PCA without ever doing a regression.